# I need to compare two excel sheets and then merge the demographics into one of the sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two sheets:

Sheet AA has 250 Names in column A and a dollar Amount in column C.

Sheet BB has 2000 names in column A and sheet BB has most of the addresses in columns h,I,j,k. Some are missing.

Objective is to get the addresses from sheet BB into sheet AA in columns E,F,G,H so I can have the addresses and the Amounts on one sheet AA. There is a few missing addresses, so leaving E F G H Blank if no addresses is there to transfer OR return a word of missing would work in columN D ON sheet AA.

I done this years ago, so I know it can be done but I forgot how.   Any help with this If statement would be greatly appreciated.

WCoops

Comment: what have you tried so far? this sounds like something better suited to using a LOOKUP function rather than an IF

Comment: Using `Power Query` merge is one option, however if you are not used to the Excel inbuilt feature then using `VLOOKUP()` or `XLOOKUP()` or using `CHOOSEROWS()`+`XMATCH()` or `INDEX()`+`MATCH()`+`MATCH()` can also workout! For the `INDEX()`+`MATCH()`+`MATCH()` i have added the last `MATCH()` for the column headers so to make it dynamic.

Comment: Have not tried anything yet right my blood pressure  hit rocking High numbers a few days before I wrote this.  Will try what you suggested. Back in the day I just wrote my own.  Guess I will try these.  Maybe it will make my life easier.

Comment: @WCoops will it be possible for you to post some sample data, with the expected output you want like. Some sample data like 15/20 lines